# Conducting a regression model with beta coefficients dependent to each other in a nonlinear way (My different independent variables are ordered)

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, autocorrelation, count-data, independence

I have a dataset of 1000 previous contests in a giveaway show where the contestant earns a random number of boxes named from "one" to "ten". The boxes contain either 1 or no gift. Each observation in the dataset has 10 independent variables ("one", "two", ....., "ten") representing the count of boxes presented to contestant for each box number and 1 dependent variable (the number of total gifts received).

[image: example of the dataset for first 6 observations]

I want to build a model to predict the number of gifts a contestant will receive based on the count of boxes presented for each box number. However, I know that the probability of getting a gift from a box is not uniform and is higher in the middle box numbers. Specifically, boxes with numbers on the tails (such as "one" or "ten") have a lower probability of containing a present, while boxes in the middle have a higher probability.

To account for this non-linear relationship, I want to constrain the beta coefficients of the independent variables to be dependent on each other in a monotonically increasing and then decreasing manner as we count from "one" to "ten" or at least as a function of most suitable fractional polynomial. This means that the effect of each box number on the number of gifts received should first increase and then decrease as we move from "one" to "ten".

What model should I use to incorporate this constraint on the beta coefficients and predict the number of gifts received based on the count of boxes presented for each box number?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why wouldn't you include the box number as a regression feature (probably with a quadratic polynomial)? That is, regress on whatever variables you would otherwise include, and then tack on the box type to raise or lower the probability it contains a present. That sounds like what you want, right?

Comment: Thank you @Dave for your answer. Actually honestly I had a hard time understanding. I clarified my question if you want to take a look again.

I can conduct model such as; y = β1*"one" + β2*"two" + β3*"three" + β4*"four" + β5*"five" + β6*"six" + β7*"seven" + β8*"eight" + β9*"nine" + β10*"ten" 

For example, if the boxes showed up to contestant is 3 box with name "four" and 4 box with name "six". when he opens all, the predicted gift count will be 3*β4 and 4*β6.

Comment: When I conduct a model such as above, I want the beta estimates of these boxes to be similar if the number on their names are closer to each other. There is a possible non-linear relation which i think possibly could be quadratic or a fractional polynomial. In other words, I would like to get estimation of beta coefficients like they are smoothed or as a function of polynomial fraction. Because boxes with close numbers in their names are more likely to have closer possibility be filled with gifts than those whose numbers are far apart.